# Getting particular values from String using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to fetch particular values from a string in Java.

Input String is:

```
String jfield = "value1, value2, auth2 = {jfield:{\"label\":\"ERP next RAW DATA\",\"value\":\"raw1\",\"description\":\"erp next description\",\"variable\":\"ascv12456789\"}},value3, auth3 = {jfield:{\"label\":\"ERP next RAW DATA\",\"value\":\"raw2\",\"description\":\"erp next description\",\"variable\":\"ascv12456789\"}}, value4";
```

The expected output is:-

```
value1, value2, value3, value4
```

What I have tried is:-

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+([,]|[,\\s]|[a-zA-Z0-9])+([,]|$)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(jfield);
if(m.find()) 
{       
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // whole matched expression
}
```

Result I am getting is:-

```
value1, value2,
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser

Comment: Regex lets you parse a specific format, which relies partially on arity and order. Your string looks like JSON, which is inherently unordered.

Comment: I believe your regex is fine. You could also use: "\\w+[0-9]{1}(, |$)", however you need to change your 'if' statement to 'while' loop, like below:

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+[0-9]{1}(, |$)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(jfield);
        while (m.find())
                System.out.println(m.group(0));

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your current approach is that your regular expression is not specific enough to match only the values you want. Instead, it is matching any sequence of one or more word characters, followed by either a comma, a comma and a space, or another word character, followed by either a comma or the end of the string.

A more specific approach would be to use the following regular expression:

"(\bvalue\d+\b)(,\s)*"

This will match any sequence of the word "value" followed by one or more digits and a comma and a space.

You can use it like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\bvalue\\d+\\b)(,\\s)*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(jfield);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(1) + " ");
}
```

This should give you the output "value1, value2, value3, value4".

Comment: this regex will only parse the alphanumeric values, what if the value is only alphabets and not numbers?